# On change of a radio button should submit form with spinning image processing

Tags: jquery

```
$('.radiobuttonclass').change(function(){       
    $('.spin-image').show();
    $('.form-class').submit();
    $('.spin-image').hide();
});
```

The above code is not working.
On radio button change, the form should be submitted. While the page is loading, an image (spinning circle) showing the process should be displayed. Once page loaded, image should be hidden.

Comment: You should use a callbak, from the submit().

Answer (score 0):

This will not work since the submit action is asynchronous meaning the submit will go and submit your form and then it will immediately go and execute the next line of code whether or not your submit has finished or not.